# Duplicate Callout CMS-Block on Home-Page

Tags: magento-1.9, home

I have an issue with my Magento-Store. I added a static cms block as callout to a custom local.xml. The code is working fine a category-pages but not on Home-Page. There the callouts are doubled.
Do you have any Idea how i can fix that?

Category-Pages **_ working _**

[image]

Home-Page **_ broken _**
Layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout> 
    <default>
    <!-- Remove callouts and rarely used stuff -->
    <remove name="right.poll"/>
    <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/> 
    <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
    <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
    <block name="left_column_block" type="cms/block">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>left_column_block</block_id> </action>
    </block>
    </default> 
</layout>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code you added and where you did that from the local.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
<default>
<!-- Remove callouts and rarely used stuff -->
<remove name="right.poll"/>
<remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
<remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
<remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
<block name="left_column_block" type="cms/block">
<action method="setBlockId">
<block_id>left_column_block</block_id>
</action>
</block>
</default>
</layout>

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have solved this issue!
Thanks to all of you trying to help me. The hint with the xml files was a good one.

The duplicate was in **cms.xml** so I had to remove the second entry there!
Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check by going into admin CMS->Static Pages->Home and then look out for layout update xml in Design tab

Comment: I double checked it - no edits inside. But i solved the issue on my own. Thank you anyways.